# Symfony - duplicate entity object setting

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony4

I am targeting all entity objects from one table to fill the other with the same data.

I want to set results that I have found in CardBalances table to Balances tablefind by the same card_id in first table.

I wrote method but it throws error:

> "Call to a member function setBalance() on array" (error for all objects)

The closest that I get is:

```
$newBalance = null;

    $existingBalances = $this->getCardBalanceRepository()->findBy(['gpsCard' => $gpsCard]);

    foreach ($existingBalances as $balance) {

        $id = $gpsCard->getId();

        if(isset($id)) {
            $newBalance = $existingBalances;
        } else {
            $newBalance = new Balance();
            $this->em->persist($newBalance);
        }

        $newBalance->setBalance($balance->getBalance());
        $newBalance->setCurrency($balance->getCurrency());
        $newBalance->setisMain($balance->getisMain());
    }

    $this->em->flush();
```

I want to set data if they are not in the database, and if are to update existing.

Comment: your code sample is ... absurd. you create a new Balance in your else block, but overwrite it in the foreach loop. I believe the if/else stuff should be inside the foreach loop ...

Comment: Use the `id` of the balance. This way, doctrine will know if you add a new item or update it

Comment: By the way you are never persisting the new balance in the loop

Comment: I updated my post. @Jakumi

Comment: I used your comments to edit my code. I updated my post. @Cid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
$newBalance = $existingBalances;
```

to

```
$newBalance = $balance;
```

because $existingBalances is an array.